# Проблема вставить JS в тело записи для разных пользователей Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Заметил такую особенность WP. Если Админ вставляет код шаринга поста с ФБ, то Скрипт при публикации не пропадает. Если же это делает это пользователь с правами Редактор или Автор, то этот скрипт удаляется из записи.

Если делает РЕДАКТОР - порядок и результат:

1. Вставляем код: [image]
2. Переключаемся в "Визуальный редактор".
3. Публикуем эту запись.
4. Результат после публикации: в визуальном редакторе:

[image]

а в текстовом редакторе:

[image]

Надеюсь, проблема понятна. Буду признателен за подсказку, где какой фильтр надо обойти или дописать.

P.S. Стоит плагин tinymce-advanced.

Comment: Я бы на Вашем месте подредактировал тему, чтобы добавлять тот или иной код автоматически, если нужно разграничить вывод для разных категорий пользователей - аналогично.

Если не ошибаюсь (давно не работал с wordpress) за вывод записи внутри темы отвечает single.php, конечно, в сложных темах могут быть дополнительные файлы, которые отвечают за вывод "особых" постов.

Answer (score 1):

[Тут](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?id=918) описано как разрешить `iframe` для `tinymce`, думаю, что тег `<script>` можно сделать аналогично.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность ).